# Generate unique ids in BigQuery data import

Tags: data-warehouse, uniqueidentifier, google-bigquery

I am using Zapier to import woocommerce orders into BigQuery and build a datawarehouse with paid orders from multiple sites. However, multiple sites generate an ID per site, not a unique id globally for all, so importing into the same table data from all the woocommerce orders will not have unique ids.

I would like BigQuery to automatically assign a unique id to every new order that enters the table. Is this possible?

Comment: Cant you use the tuple site_id, order_id as a key?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, there is not site_id in the woocommerce database, and the order_id is only unique to 1 website not all of them.

Comment: You have nothing that identifies a site?